# Aquatic turtles bit each other

Tags: reptiles, turtles, biting, injury

I've 2 male aquatic red-eared slider turtles and they've lived together in a 50 gallon tank for 6 months. One of the turtles bit the other and hurt his front leg (There is wound on his leg now).

How can I help except going to the vet?

Comment: Nearly all aquatic turtles are loners. This means in nature they do only meet to mate. If together in one tank, they need much more space than 50 gallon, more some thing like a pond with two basking areas to avoid fights.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I help except going Vet?

If it's more than a scratch you'll still want to go to the vet to make sure that it doesn't need stitches. The best you can do at home is try to keep it from getting infected.

A bath in Nolvasan solution (50% Nolvasan 50% water) should help keep the bacteria from taking over the cut, gently work it around the area with a clean gauze pad. Then rinse with clean warm water and apply a bandage with an antibiotic with another clean gauze pad. Neosporin will work, and so will Mycatracin or Bacitracin.

It's important that while the cut is healing, the area remains dry, so you'll need to keep him in a dry terrarium until it's healed. That way the antibiotics are able to work and the cut doesn't get infected with bacteria from the water.

Giving him some vitamin A supplements and a bit of honey should help ease the healing process as well. Then just make sure to clean and dress the wound daily until it heals.

Finally for the future, since there has been aggression shown towards each other, I'd suggest considering splitting the two up between two tanks as it's pretty common to see the same behaviour show up again later. If you do put them back together you'll want to keep a close eye on them during feeding times, as that's when they can get the most aggressive.

You'll want to give them more space as well. The rule of thumb is about 10 gallons of water per inch of turtle, so generally 2 sliders are kept in a 125 gallon tank. Not having enough space makes them more likely to be aggressive towards each other.